# Handle exceptions inside class method

Tags: typescript, exception, decorator

I am wondering if there is a way to handle error exceptions that occures inside class method other way than having try catch wrapped code snippet inside class method.

Found solution with decorators, but not sure it provides same functionality.

Comment: could you provide an example of what you want in code.

Comment: For instance I have next code snippet 
`class {
   handleCreateQueue(data) {
     const queue = this.queueService.create({...data});
  }
}`

so for instance create method can throw an exception especially orm, so that i need to handle it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you mean like this:

```
function CatchError(target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const method = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        try {
            return method.apply(this, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error occurred in ${propertyName}:`, error);
            // Handle the error or rethrow it
            // You can also perform specific actions based on error type
        }
    };
}
```

example of use:

```
class MyService {
    constructor(private queueService: QueueService) {}

    @CatchError
    handleCreateQueue(data: any) {
        const queue = this.queueService.create({...data});
        // Other operations...
    }
}
```

Here is a way to do it without decorators, I am not sure which one you wanted:

```
function withErrorHandling(fn: Function) {
    return function(...args: any[]) {
        try {
            return fn.apply(this, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error occurred:", error);
            // Handle the error or rethrow it
        }
    };
}

class MyService {
    handleCreateQueue = withErrorHandling((data: any) => {
        // Your method implementation
        const queue = this.queueService.create({...data});
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: hmmm, I think both soloutions are suit for me. 
I have one more question whether with these approaches above I can replace somehow try cath block
for instance:

`class MyService {
    constructor(private queueReposirory: QueueRepository) {}
    private handleCreateQueue: BotHandler = async (bot) => {
    bot.onReplyToMassage // lalla getting response from user with data
       const data = msg.text;
       try {
           const queue = await this.queueRepository.create(data);
        }
        catch (e: any) { 
       await bot.sendMessage(chatId, e.message); 
   }
}`

Comment: the solutions above get rid of the try catch inside of the class and  extract the logic elsewhere I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: Okay, never mind, what about this 
`function withErrorHandling(fn: Function) {
    return function(...args: any[]) {
        try {
            return fn.apply(this, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error occurred:", error);
            // Handle the error or rethrow it
        }
    };
}`
Does it handle errors that thorws async operations inside function fn?

Comment: you would just edit this function. put async before function then await before fn.apply()

would work for that specific requirement in your comment